# virtual hosts not working

Tags: apache

I'm trying to add a virtual host to my server.

I want `a.example.com` to point to `C:/xampp/htdocs/public`.

I want `b.example.com` to point to `C:/xampp/htdocs/b.example.com`.

This is my virtual hosts setup:

```
<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName a.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/public/"
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost *>
    ServerName b.example.com
    DocumentRoot "C:/xampp/htdocs/b.example.com/"
</VirtualHost>
```

For some reason, it just points to `C:/xampp/htdocs/public`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I finally figured it out. you have to set `NameVirtualHost *`. Once I added that, it started working

Answer (score 0):

You can also define each virtual host by the VirtualHost, like:

```
<VirtualHost b.example.com:80>
```

You can then use `<VirtualHost *`> as a catch-all default